# Referring to a diagram

Tags: technical-writing, grammar, graphics

In a math book, should I write "diagram 3" or explicitly "diagram at the figure 3", when referring to a diagram in a displayed figure? (The title of the figure (as autogenerated by LaTeX) is "Figure 3." not "Diagram 3".)

Comment: What are the diagrams of and why are there more than one per figure?

Comment: @TriskalJM Why have you decided that there more than one diagram per figure? Usually there is at most one diagram per figure. In my case a diagram is a part of a figure. A figure may consist of a caption, a diagram, and a description (so called "legend") of what the diagram means

Comment: I thought multiple diagrams would be weird, but I thought it'd be best to ask. When referring to it in the text, the Figure is counted as a unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to it as *Figure 3*. For the purposes of the text, the diagram is the part that counts. The caption and anything else are information that augments the diagram.